# Python: How to check if an imported module/package/class is from standard library

Tags: python

Is there a possibility to verify if an import comes from the standard library or not?

For example:

```
from math import sin #from the standard library.
from my_module import MyClass #not from the standard library.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this, as the Python standard library is not implemented in a special way - to Python, there is no distinction between the standard library and other modules.

At best, you could use [the `inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/inspect.html) to try and find some indicators, for example, using [`inspect.getsourcefile()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcefile) to find where the source file is located, then using that to check if it's a core library. This won't work particularly well, however, as any modules in C will return a TypeError as they are builtins - but you can't presume they are from the standard library, as any C extension module will do the same thing.

If you **really** have to do this, my suggestion would be to keep a list of standard library module names and do it that way - it's not a great solution, but it's likely to be more stable than any alternative.

Comment: Too bad Python does not put all its standard library packages/modules in a python package, as Java does with its standard library. That makes the task of asserting if a package/module belongs to standard library trivial.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Is it really something you need to know often? The use case of not having to type `python.` for everything outweighs it by a mile, as I see it.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your own modules in a specific directory, you could do something looking at the module's `__file__` property:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.__file__
'/usr/lib64/python2.6/os.pyc'

>>> import my_module
>>> my_module.__file__
'/path/to/my_packages/.../my_module.pyc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Below source code will tell you whether a module a standard Python module or not

```
def is_standard_module(module_name):
    if module_name in sys.builtin_module_names:
        return True
    installation_path = None
    try:
        installation_path = importlib.import_module(module_name).__file__
    except ImportError:
        return False
    linux_os, _, _ = platform.linux_distribution()
    return "dist-packages" not in installation_path if linux_os == "Ubuntu" else "site-packages" not in installation_path
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.10+, you can use [sys.stdlib_module_names](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdlib_module_names)

```
import sys
import types

def is_stdlib(module: str | types.ModuleType) -> bool:
    """
    Return True if module is in stdlib
    """

    if isinstance(module, str):
        return module.split('.')[0] in sys.stdlib_module_names

    if isinstance(module, types.ModuleType):
        return module.__name__.split('.')[0] in sys.stdlib_module_names

    raise TypeError('module must be a string or module object')
```